# Definite Integral Problem up-to infinity

Tags: definite-integrals

I was trying to solve simple integration problem, integration x from 0-infinite. Is there any particular answer to the question from any other methods? My try is I've shown on picture below. 
[image]

Comment: You forgot to change limits when you substituted z. Further as x approaches infinite, the integral also approaches infinite

Comment: [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) reference to help you type maths directly on the site.

Comment: @downvoters The question has been significantly improved, an attempt has been given.

Comment: I don't think it's needed to type all those equation because what matters is i am here to learn. I find it's easy to type on Microsoft Word platform rather typing whole equation, which makes a lot more easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake: As you change your variable to $z$, the variable is not change back.

Remark: Rather than $90$, you might want to work with radian.

$$\lim_{M \to \infty} \int_0^M x \, dx= \lim_{M \to \infty}\frac{M^2}2 = \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

I would re-interpret problem to be for $0<a$, what is the limit as $a$ goes to infinity of $\int_0^a xdx.$  When $0<a$, $\int_0^a xdx = \displaystyle\frac{a^2}{2}.$  Therefore, the (re-interpreted) problem is equivalent to asking: what is the limit as $a$ goes to infinity of $\displaystyle\frac{a^2}{2}.$  Obviously, as $a$ goes to infinity, $\displaystyle\frac{a^2}{2}$ goes to infinity.

This approach is very similar to Siong Thye Goh's approach, except that I scrap the whole polar coordinates / radians approach and just stay with the algebra.